Recieving double trigger events via WebSocket?
I have an ASP.NET web application that helps picking items in a warehouse, and it is using NIMMSTA scanners to trigger the picking of an item. If anyone is interested, NIMMSTA documentation for their library I am using is available here: https://docs.nimmsta.com/web/7.0/
Long story short, everything works, but sometimes I get double input from the scanners. The scanners are using websockets to communicate with the application, and it looks like one trigger event can sometimes call the response several times. My guess is that my websocket handling might be the issue?
I'll be posting a lot of code down below, but I believe the main focus will be on the websocket handler code.
I'm not too familiar with websockets, but got a simple websocket handler template that looks like this:
public class WebSocketHandler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(EchoWebSocket);
    }
}

private async Task EchoWebSocket(AspNetWebSocketContext socketContext)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    var result = await socketContext.WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

    while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        await socketContext.WebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
        result = await socketContext.WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    }

    await socketContext.WebSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}

This seems to work, as it allows communication with the scanners and their own desktop application. I can send various messages to the scanners, get their trigger events, etc.
But I wonder if the while loop until there is response is causing it to re-send the same trigger if the application is too slow?
Anyway, just for some extra info if needed, this is the script to set up the whole thing:
$(document).ready(function () {
NIMMSTA.requestSendTimeout = 1000;
NIMMSTA.maxCommunicationRetries = 1;
NIMMSTA.keepAlwaysConnected = true;

NIMMSTA.onReady(function () {
    const connectionManager = new NimmstaConnectionManager();

    connectionManager.socketConnectEvent.subscribe((event) => {
        NIMMSTA_ShowDeviceStatus(connectionManager.devices.length);
    });
    connectionManager.socketDisconnectEvent.subscribe((event) => {
        if (event.currentConnectionCount < 1)
        NIMMSTA_ShowDeviceStatus(-1);
    });
    connectionManager.connectEvent.subscribe((device) => {
        device.setLayout(new StandbyLayout());
        DeviceSetUp(device);
        NIMMSTA_ShowDeviceStatus(connectionManager.devices.length);
    });
});

NIMMSTA.onError(function (error) {
    NIMMSTA_ShowDeviceStatus(-1);
    NIMMSTA.tryConnect();
});
});

Then what's important from here is the DeviceSetUp function that looks like this:
function DeviceSetUp(device) {
device.scanEvent.subscribe((event) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "OrderVisualization.aspx/OnScan",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        data: "{ScanContent: '" + event.barcode + "'}",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(response.d);
            device.setLayoutFor(10000, new ScanSuccessLayout(data.Message, data.PartNumber, data.Quantity, data.Unit));
            device.triggerLEDBurstParameters(5, 500, 250, 0, 255, 0);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            var responseData = $.parseJSON(response.responseText)
            device.setLayoutFor(10000, new ScanErrorLayout(responseData.Message));
            device.triggerLEDBurstParameters(5, 500, 250, 255, 0, 0);
            device.triggerBeeperBurstParameters(3, 500, 250, 100);
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('VerySecretHiddenRefreshButton').click();
});
device.disconnectEvent.subscribe((event) => {
    const connectionManager = new NimmstaConnectionManager();
    NIMMSTA_ShowDeviceStatus(connectionManager.devices.length);
});

console.log('Scanner device set up.');
}

As you can see, on the event of a scanning, it calls a OnScan webmethod from the OrderVisualization page, which is handling the scan (updates database, transfers item in SAP, etc). I won't post it here, since it's long and full of pointless details. But it works. The only problem is that it sometimes gets called two times, which obviously results in issues - either double item picking, or "item already picked" errors.
So my guess is that the issue might be with the WebSocketHandler code I posted on the top, since it seems to resend the message if there are no results. Should I just remove the while loop? Or place the SendAsync before the while loop, and only keep the RecieveAsync in the while loop?
Any tips are appreciated, thank you in advance.
